# Show that the error $\mid f(x)-P_2(x) \mid$ is bounded by $\frac{\sqrt2e}{3}$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Let $f(x)=e^x\cos(x)$ and let $P_2(x)$ be the 2nd Taylor Polynomial for $f$ about $x_0=0$.

(i) Show that the error $\mid f(x)-P_2(x) \mid$ is bounded by $\frac{\sqrt2e}{3}$ on $[0,1]$.

(ii) Show that the error in using $\int^1_0P_2(x)dx$ to approximate $\int^1_0f(x)dx$ is bounded by:
$$\bigl|\int^1_0f(x)dx - \int^1_0P_2(x)dx \bigr|\le\frac{2\sqrt2}{3}(3-e)$$

Ok... So my issue is that I sorta see it. But I just can't piece it together.

So I'll right it down on and maybe some of you can help me out here.
$$\bigl| f(x)-P_2(x) \bigr|=\bigl|R_2(x)\bigr|$$
So $\bigl|R_2(x)\bigr|$ is what i need to show that is bounded.

$$\bigl|R_2(x)\bigr| = \bigl| \frac{-e^\xi(\sin(\xi)+\cos(\xi))}{3}x^3 \bigr|=\bigl| \frac{e^\xi(\sin(\xi)+\cos(\xi))}{3}x^3 \bigr|$$ The latter equality is achieved because $|-a|=|a|$.

It is further given that we can use the identity:
$$\bigl|\sin(\xi)+\cos(\xi)\bigr|\le \sqrt2 \space \forall \xi\in[0,1]$$
Furthermore, it doesn't take a lot to see that $0\le e^\xi\le e$ in this range as well.
Adding to that is $0 \le x^3 \le 1$.

Now it kinda looks like all the ingredients are there but I just don't know how to merge them all up together.

I'd like to add that i'm relatively new to this aspect of math so i'm not 100% sure that the equations I developed were correct.

---UPDATE (i) was done thanks to the help below---

Now i'm stuck with part 2. If i work off the notion that $\xi$ is dependant on $x$ and thus i can't take it out of the integral, i'm left with as follows:

$$\frac{1}{6} \bigl| [-2x^3(e^\xi sin\xi)]^1_0 - [3x^2(e^\xi (cos\xi - sin\xi))]^1_0 + [6xe^\xi cos\xi)]^1_0 - \int^1_0 6e^\xi cos\xi dx \bigr|$$

Well i think you guys can see my problem.

1: how does the constraint [0,1] factor into $\xi$

2: how do I evaluate the final integral?

Comment: oh i meant to type $e^\xi \le e$. That is true right?

Comment: Are you sure your error term shouldn't have an $x^3$ instead of an $x^4$?

Comment: @πr8 damn... i've been doing this question for the pass hour my head is just not working right. yeah it's suppose to be $x^3$ thanks. I think that kinda helps me work out the integral. thanks!

Comment: No worries - good luck finishing it off! As a general rule, for the nth order Taylor series, the remainder should be $\sim (x-a)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Alright. thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

$$\bigl|R_2(x)\bigr| = \bigl| \frac{-e^\xi(\sin(\xi)+\cos(\xi))}{3}x^3 \bigr|=\bigl| \frac{e^\xi(\sin(\xi)+\cos(\xi))}{3}x^3 \bigr|\le\bigl| \frac{e^1(\sin(\xi)+\cos(\xi))}{3}x^3 \bigr|$$
because we're in $[0,1]$. Then:
$$\bigl|\frac{e^1(\sin(\xi)+\cos(\xi))}{3}x^3 \bigr|\le\bigl|\frac{e^1(\sin(\xi)+\cos(\xi))}{3}1^3 \bigr|$$
again, because we're in $[0,1]$. Finally:
$$\bigl|\frac{e^1(\sin(\xi)+\cos(\xi))}{3}1^3 \bigr|\le\bigl|\frac{e^1(\sqrt2)}{3}1^3 \bigr|$$
by the bound you give. Putting it all back together:

$$\bigl|R_2(x)\bigr|\le\frac{\sqrt2 e}{3}$$

For the integral, backtrack a bit to show $$\vert R_2(x)\vert\le\frac{\sqrt2x^3e^x}{3}$$

Integrating this from $0$ to $1$ (using integration by parts a few times along the way) gives the desired inequality.

Comment: So what i'm seeing is that I have to take the upper bound of each of the inequalities involve to derive the final upper bound? P.S. thanks for your help!

Comment: In this case, yes - it's just bounding each part of the remainder independently, and then reassembling it all to give a final bound.

Comment: Alright! thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Sorry, do you have any clue how should I approach (ii)? I tried to remove $\frac{-e^\xi(sin\xi + cos\xi)}{3}$ out of the integral but the answer isn't matching. Is it because $\xi$ is dependent on x -> hence the integral will affect it too?

Comment: Yeah, any factor you absorb out of the integral will have to be a constant.

Comment: So... I've added my work to the question, if you could help with it that would be great. but it's alright if you're busy, you've really helped me a lot! thanks again!